# spring batch remote partitioning design advice

Tags: spring-batch

We have to process 4-5 million records and write them to file. So we are developing POC where our master step reads data from master table and creates partitions. Each partition has info about which rows needs to be processed by slave. Our slave just take those rows, applies biz rules and write them to file. This is working fine as remote slaves.

Now my question is can we make those remote slave multithreaded? Is yer then it there any impact on data consistency?

Comment: Why not just add more partitions?

Comment: We have constraint of resources on server where it is not easy to add just new slave, so i wanted to make multithreaded remote step with 2 slaves we have. Assigning resources is not in my control and process takes too long

Comment: Why can't you run multiple slaves within the same server?  I commonly deploy each node to run multiple slaves in threads.  The overhead shouldn't be that much different than a multithreaded step.

Comment: That's good point. Let me try that how it is improving performance.

Comment: Michael, I would like to ask multithreaded question differently. Is it possible to have multiple MDP(message driven pojo) on remote step, to improve performance without adding too many slave? By default we have one consumer/MDP when we add slave as we did not configured it explicitly, so thinking add concurrent consumers can improve performance by picking diff partition message off the queue

Comment: Take a look at my repo here: https://github.com/mminella/Spring-Batch-Talk-2.0  The sample application in that repo is a remote partitioned job.  Each slave node is configured to run 3 partitions concurrently.  There is a video linked in the README to see the associated talk as well.  I commonly create more, smaller partitions if there is any concern about load balancing as well (as in that sample's example).